# How to move to the next buffer when using `M-x multi-occur`?

Tags: emacs

When using `M-x multi-occur` how do I go to the next buffer? It appears the results only show for the first buffer.

I cant seem to find the answer to this obvious question anywhere! NB: I am a complete Emacs novice.

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke function `next-error`, which is typically bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> (that last key is a backquote).  It should automatically advance to the next buffer when there are no more matches in the current buffer.